# Connect two subnets over dd-wrt router

Tags: networking, routing

I would like to connect a static IP subnet over a DD-WRT router to another subnet.

My setup

- 192.168.22.2 PCs with static IP connected via LAN to
- 192.168.22.1 DD-WRT Router connected via wifi to
- 192.168.0.9 another router

From 192.168.22.1 I can ping everywhere but **the problem is from 192.168.22.2 I can't ping 192.168.0.1** (Destination Host Unreachable).

I have setup default routes:

@192.168.22.2$ ip route
default via 192.168.22.1 dev eth0

@192.168.22.1$ ip route
default via 192.168.0.9 dev eth1

I guess the problem is at 192.168.22.1 where I have the two interfaces eth0 (LAN) and eth1 (wifi). I am running DD-WRT on a Linksys WRT54GL. This router looks internal like this:

[image: Linksys WRT54G]

DD-WRT creates a bridge br0 for eth0 and a vlan0 and vlan1. Not sure if this is related to the problem.

**Update: iptables**

Basically I am trying to connect to subnets. Found some stuff about that and updated my iptables so it now accepts all FORWARD, INPUT and OUTPUT: `iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT`

Also I removed all other rules and checked `iptables -L -nv` that my ACCEPT is used. But still `Destination Host Unreachable`. `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` returns 1.